# Angular using import from assets folder

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, single-page-application, angular8

I have a library installed via npm and one of the modules I have modified.

```
python.js
```

So, just because if I delete the node_modules folder and run npm install I would lose the changes I need to put this module elsewhere?

I currently import it like this:

```
import 'brace/mode/phython';
```

So if I move my modified version of `phython.js` into the assets folder...

How do I import it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this to see if it work

```
import 'assets/brace/mode/phython';
```